# Is there a way to define text inside a Konva.Rect Class by using only Konva.Rect class attributes?

Tags: class, attributes, konvajs

I am using Konva.js in my project and I have a specific need to define text inside a draggable rectangle that was defined using Konva.Rect() class.Is there a way to achieve this without using a separate Konva.Text() or Konva.Label() class object since that would become way too complicated.

Open to suggestions.Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are:

1. Use Konva.Label
2. Create a draggable group with rectangle and text inside
3. Create one custom shape. Draw rectangle and text inside `sceneFunc`

Comment: I see.Thanks for the elaboration.However, this would still involve using more than one Konva controls I guess.

Comment: Hi, Do you by chance have an example code for the same? I new to Konva and struggling to achieve this in my `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` application. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69842757/7584240